# For Loop or While break but normal code works

Tags: r, loops

The R Code works fine when i run with out any loops but i convert into for loop or while loop , it fails with error below. however when i clear the memory using `rm(list = ls()); gc()` , some times it works and fails as well.

> Error in nn_matchC(treat, ord, ratio, replace, discarded, distance,
> ex,  :    length of 'dimnames' [1] not equal to array extent In
> addition: There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the
> first 50)

```
for (cSegNbr in 1:nrow(dfSegNbr)){
  segnbr <- dfSegNbr[cSegNbr, "segment_nbr"]
  slsdecile <- dfSegNbr[cSegNbr, "sales_decile"]
  promodecile <- dfSegNbr[cSegNbr, "sm_rate_decile"]
  BPCdecile <- dfSegNbr[cSegNbr, "bpc_sales_decile"]
  HCdecile <- dfSegNbr[cSegNbr, "hc_sales_decile"]
  Otherdecile <- dfSegNbr[cSegNbr, "other_sales_decile"]
  ## print(paste('select * from SB_CAREPASS.cp_cntrl_pool_cohort_final_new_nl where cohort_month=201908  and segment_nbr=', segnbr,' and other_sales_decile=',Otherdecile,' and hc_sales_decile=',HCdecile,' and bpc_sales_decile=',BPCdecile,' and sales_decile=',slsdecile, ' and sm_rate_decile=',promodecile))
  df <- sqlQuery(ch, paste('select * from SB_CAREPASS.cp_cntrl_pool_cohort_final_new_nl where cohort_month=202103  and segment_nbr=', segnbr,' and other_sales_decile=',Otherdecile,' and hc_sales_decile=',HCdecile,' and bpc_sales_decile=',BPCdecile,' and sales_decile=',slsdecile, ' and sm_rate_decile=',promodecile))
  m.out= matchit(test_control ~ q1_sls+q2_sls+q2_sls+q4_sls+sls_nbr_of_wks+fs_sales_amt_m1+fs_sales_amt_m2+fs_sales_amt_m3+fs_sales_amt_m4+fs_sales_amt_m5+fs_sales_amt_m6+fs_sales_amt_m7+fs_sales_amt_m8+fs_sales_amt_m9+fs_sales_amt_m10+fs_sales_amt_m11+fs_sales_amt_m12+fs_sales+avg_bskt_size+promo_depth+SB_penetration+personalized_cpn+base_cpn+mass_cpn+phr_flag+bty_club_flag+card_tenure_years+cust_age,data=df, method="nearest", ratio=1)
  m.data1<-match.data(m.out)
  df_total <- rbind(df_total,m.data1)
  print(cSegNbr)
  ## print(paste('select * from SB_CAREPASS.cp_cntrl_pool_cohort_final_new_nl where cohort_month=201908  and segment_nbr=', segnbr,' and sales_decile=',slsdecile, ' and sm_rate_decile=',promodecile))
}
```

Comment: Look at the value of you loop index at the time of the error. That will tell you which row has problematic values BUT  you didn't see fit to include that information.

Comment: not able to follow you comments. should i print the value of the i where it is throwing error. i have the print(cSegNbr) as well

Comment: I don't see any `i` in that code. The index variable is `cSegNbr` was being printed. The value that is one greater than the last `cSegNbr` value is the one that is causing the error.